# How to append select angularjs with options json

Tags: angularjs, json, append

This code is actually working without append function but when I append it, I can see the select but the only data inside is the brackets {{option1.nomcarac}}
[image: append function]

I would like to append and receive my options, look likes easy but killed my brain for this day

[image]

Comment: You have to compile an element using `$compile` service with respective `$scope`.. like`$compile(elementToAdd)($scope)`.. apart from this issue, doing DOM manipulation from controller is considered as anti-pattern..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for your problem is this:

```
var elem = angular.element("<select><option ng-repeat='option in options1' 
value='option1.nomcarac'>{{option.nomcarac}}</option></select>");
 $(".testo").append($compile(elem)($scope));
```

Here's plunker link for this: https://plnkr.co/edit/lotJ3ndRIGDp5pQqqKH0?p=preview

But you should not follow this jquery approach for adding field dynamically into the angular form. What you can do instead is having ng-repeat on input field which you want to add dynamically to any number of times and having inputs array for the model values of those dynamically created inputs. So this's ho you can achieve that:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in selects">
    <select ng-model="item.value"><option ng-repeat='option1 in options1' 
     value='{{option1.nomcarac}}' >{{option1.nomcarac}}</option></select>
    <button ng-click="getValue(item)">get input value</button>
</div>
```

And in controller have function like:

```
$scope.addSelectItem = function(){
    fieldname = "Field " + count;
    $scope.selects.push({name: fieldname});
    count++;
}
```

You can have another ng-repeat for another kind of input field. So in this way the fields will be added more cleanly.
Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/nptQEOOxt7cAmHJ2sT30?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much fo your complet & comprehensive answer !

Answer (score 0):

> If your HTML string contains an angular expression then you'll need to
>   use $compile.

As per the Angular official documentation of [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service.The compile service is **:**

> Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template
>   function, which can then be used to link scope and the template
>   together.

**HTML :**

```
<div ng-controller="DemoController">
  <dynamic-element selectOption='htmlString'></dynamic-element>
</div>
```

**Directive :**

```
(function(){
"use strict";
angular.module("CompileDirective", [])
  .directive('dynamicElement', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
      return { 
        restrict: 'E', 
        scope: {
            selectOption: "="
        },
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var template = $compile(scope.selectOption)(scope);
            element.replaceWith(template);               
        }
      }
  }])
  .controller("DemoController", ["$scope", function($scope){
      $scope.htmlString = '<select><option ng-repeat='option1 in options1' 
value='option1.nomcarac'>{{option1.nomcarac}}</option></select>';
  }])

}());
```